# Syntax error at or near "1" -- PostGIS in Action -- Chapter 11 SQL data dump

Tags: postgis, postgresql, syntax, debugging

I'm following along with PostGIS in Action, 2nd ed., chapter 11, while attempting the SQL dump from the data files and I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 189: 1 0101000020E610000060C77F81A01E6340132C0E677E293BC0 0 0 0 4...
```

I've already looked at the errata, google, PostgresSQL docs (9.2, 9.5 copy differences); and double checked tab separated in relation to the stdin.

```sql
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.2.4
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.3beta2

TOC entry 3966 (class 0 OID 10834271)
-- Dependencies: 342
-- Data for Name: aussie_track_points; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: ch11; Owner: postgres
--

COPY aussie_track_points (ogc_fid, geom, track_fid, track_seg_id, track_seg_point_id, ele, "time", course, speed, magvar, geoidheight, name, cmt, "desc", src, url, urlname, sym, type, fix, sat, hdop, vdop, pdop, ageofdgpsdata, dgpsid) FROM stdin;
-- 1    0101000020E610000060C77F81A01E6340132C0E677E293BC0  0   0   040.899999999999999 2009-07-18 04:30:00-04  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  3d  \N  0.96999999999999997 2.1699999999999999  2.3799999999999999  \N  \N
-- 2    0101000020E61000000723F609A01E6340F51263997E293BC0  0   0   1   40.399999999999999  2009-07-18 04:30:14-04  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  3d  \N  0.91000000000000003 0.88    1.27    \N  \N
-- 3    0101000020E6100000A9C1340C9F1E6340E7C8CA2F83293BC0  0   0   2   41.799999999999997  2009-07-18 04:30:20-04  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  3d  \N  0.96999999999999997 1.8999999999999999  2.1299999999999999  \N  \N
-- 4    0101000020E610000038DBDC989E1E6340B610E4A084293BC0  0   0   3   41.299999999999997  2009-07-18 04:30:26-04  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  3d  \N  0.91000000000000003 0.88    1.27    \N  \N
-- 5    0101000020E6100000020D36759E1E6340F52F49658A293BC0  0   0   4   41.299999999999997  2009-07-18 04:30:43-04  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  3d  \N  0.91000000000000003 0.88    1.27    \N  \N
```

Comment: When are you getting this error? When you try and restore from the dump? How exactly are you doing that? Give the commands - I suspect its because PostgreSQL has a different idea of what stdin is at that point...

Comment: I was attempting to load the file using the SQL editor, which had worked for all the previous files. I was able to solve the problem by using psql. Thanks for the effort....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

1) Use psql in the command line instead of loading with the SQL editor. 
2) If you're using Windows and not logged in as postgres, add the -U flag to: psql -d postgis_in_action -U postgres -f ..path/ch11_data.sql -- for some reason, the username is not being picked up from the pgpass.conf file.